# Filtering array of nested arrays using conition object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I've object array (Json format) like below

```
var datas = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"1-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"1-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"2-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"2-2",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"3-1",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
            {
                "id":"3-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  }
]
```

And i tried like below

```
var filteredData = datas.filter( t => t.tests.filter(o => o.isSelected));
```

to get all **data** with **tests** of `"isSelected"` value is `true`, and it is not working. Is there anyway to get data in below format.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    // Here 10 fields
    "t": [
            {
                "id":"1-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            }
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"2-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"2-2",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
        ]
  }
]
```

Comment: *"I've Json array like below"* Nope, you have an object array. :-) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript/TypeScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Please reread the `json` tag description... especially what is in capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're returning the inner `filter` result (an array) from your outer `filter` callback. An array is truthy, so you're keeping everything.

You need to handle each outer object in two steps:

1. Filtering its `tests`, and
2. Filtering it out entirely if its `tests` is empty

So:

```
var filteredData = datas.filter(t => {
  t.tests = t.tests.filter(o => o.isSelected);
  return t.tests.length !== 0;
});
```

```js
var datas = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"1-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"1-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"2-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"2-2",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"3-1",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
            {
                "id":"3-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  }
]

var filteredData = datas.filter(t => {
  t.tests = t.tests.filter(o => o.isSelected);
  return t.tests.length !== 0;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or if you really want a concise arrow function:

So:

```
var filteredData = datas.filter(t =>
  (t.tests = t.tests.filter(o => o.isSelected)).length !== 0
);
```

```js
var datas = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"1-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"1-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"2-1",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
            {
                "id":"2-2",
                "isSelected": true,
            },
        ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    // Here 10 fields
    "tests": [
            {
                "id":"3-1",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
            {
                "id":"3-2",
                "isSelected": false,
            },
        ]
  }
]

var filteredData = datas.filter(t =>
  (t.tests = t.tests.filter(o => o.isSelected)).length !== 0
);

console.log(filteredData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```